# Generics and using newly created methods in a Class that implements Iterable Interface

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I am working on a program that checks the validity of a sudoku solution. I am close to having it finished, but for some reason when I try to call certain methods I have created, the compiler returns that they are undefined.

There are three main classes:

1. A sudoku class, which implements the iterable interface. It contains a two dimensional array that is the puzzle. The constructor takes a file from scanner input and builds the puzzle. It has a iterator method to satisfy the interface requirements. This method returns an interator of type SudokuIterator.
2. A SudokuIterator class, which implements the Iterator Interface. This is a private inner class of the Sudoku class. It also has a 2 dimensional array and a cursor as attributes. It has the standard hasNext(), next(), and a remove() stub to satisfy the interface. I have also added a nextColumn() and nextBox() that return an array based on the cursor position. The next method has been overridden to return rows.
3. Finally is the Validator. This method is the main method. It has a method isSolution() that returns a boolean depending on analysis of each array returned from methods defined  in the SudokuIterator Class.

And this is where my problems arise; when use the iterator method to instantiate and return a SudokuIterator and try to then use my added nextColumn() and nextBox() methods, the compiler returns that those methods are undefined for Iterator.

Any advice or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Sudoku class represents the matrix of cells in a Sudoku puzzle
 * @version 01/05/2012
 * @author Bob Wilson
 */

public class Sudoku implements Iterable<Cell []>
{
  private Cell [] [] puzzle;

  /**
   * Default constructor should not be called.  Make it private.
   */
  private Sudoku() {}

  /**
   * Puzzle constructor that uses a Scanner object to read a file.
   * File contains 81 numbers that are the values of the 81 cells.
   * @param file a Scanner object on a File object
   */
  public Sudoku(Scanner file)
  {
    int size = file.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Size: " + size);
    puzzle = new Cell[size][size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        puzzle[i][j] = new Cell(file.nextInt());
  }

  public int getLength(){
        return this.puzzle.length;
    }


   class SudokuIterator implements Iterator<Cell []> {

        private Cell [][] puzzle;
        private int cursor;

        public SudokuIterator(Cell [][] puzzle){

            this.puzzle = puzzle;
            cursor = 1;

        }


        public boolean hasNext(){
            if(cursor <= this.puzzle.length){
                return true;
            }
            return false;   
    }
        public Cell[] next(){
            Cell[] row = puzzle[cursor-1];
            cursor++;
            return row;
        }

        public Cell[] nextColumn(){
            Cell[] column = new Cell[puzzle.length];
            for(int i = 0; i < puzzle.length; i++){
                column[i] = puzzle[i][cursor-1];
            }
            cursor++;
            return column;
        }

        public Cell[] nextBox(){
            Cell[] box = new Cell[puzzle.length];
            int boxIndex = 0;
            for(int i = ((cursor - 1)/((int)Math.sqrt(puzzle.length)))*(int)Math.sqrt(puzzle.length) ; i < ((cursor - 1)/((int)Math.sqrt(puzzle.length)))*(int)Math.sqrt(puzzle.length) + (int)Math.sqrt(puzzle.length); i++){
                for(int j = (((cursor - 1) + ((int)Math.sqrt(puzzle.length))) % ((int)Math.sqrt(puzzle.length))) * ((int)Math.sqrt(puzzle.length)); j < (((cursor - 1) + ((int)Math.sqrt(puzzle.length))) % ((int)Math.sqrt(puzzle.length))) * ((int)Math.sqrt(puzzle.length)) + ((int)Math.sqrt(puzzle.length)); j++){
                    box[boxIndex] = puzzle[i][j];
                }
            }
            cursor++;
            return box;
        }
        public void remove(){}
  }
  /**
   * Generates and returns a String representation of the puzzle cells
   * @return A String representing the contents of the puzzle array
   */
  public String toString()
  {
    // display the puzzle
    String value = "Puzzle is:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < puzzle.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < puzzle[i].length; j++) 
        value += puzzle[i][j].toString();
      value += "\n";
    }
    return value;
  }

  /**
   * Instantiates and returns a new SudokuIterator object
   * @return A SudokuIterator object on the puzzle array
   */

  public SudokuIterator iterator(){

     SudokuIterator iterator = new SudokuIterator(this.puzzle);
     return iterator;

  }


  }
  /* 201340 */

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

/** 
 * This class instantiates a Sudoku object passing a Scanner on a
 * file to the Sudoku constructor.  It prints the puzzle using the
 * Sudoku toString method.  It determines if the digit matrix is a
 * valid solution for a Sudoku puzzle or not and prints the result.
 * 
 * @version 01/05/2012
 * @author Bob Wilson
 * 
 */

public class SudokuValidator
{
  private Sudoku puzzle;

  /**
   * @param args - not used
   */
  public static void main( String [] args)
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter name of file containing puzzle to verify");   
    SudokuValidator myValidator = new SudokuValidator(scan.nextLine());
    System.out.println(myValidator.isSolution());
  }

  public SudokuValidator(String fileName)
  {
    Scanner file = null;
    try
    {
      file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("Bad file name");
      System.exit(0);
    }

    puzzle = new Sudoku(file);
    System.out.println(puzzle);
  }

  public boolean isSolution(){


      boolean flag = true;
      Iterator<Cell[]> game = puzzle.iterator();

      while(game.hasNext()){
          Cell[] row = game.next();
          Cell[] column = game.nextColumn();
          Cell[] box = game.nextBox();


          for(Cell i: row){
              for(Cell j: row){
                  if(j.equals(i.getValue())){
                      flag = false;
                      return flag;
                  }
              }
          }
      }  
      return flag;
  }
}  /* 201340 */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is, the declared type of `game` reference variable is `Iterator`, which doesn't define any `nextColumn()` method, so compiler cannot find it. You can fix this by changing the declared type to `Sudoku.SudokuIterator` (Since that is an inner class).

Change:

```
Iterator<Cell[]> game = puzzle.iterator();
```

to:

```
Sudoku.SudokuIterator game = puzzle.iterator();
```

Comment: I am now getting a compilation error saying, "SudokuIterator cannot be resolved to a type."

Comment: @Atache. Add an import to your class.

Comment: @Atache. If you have your classes in default package, which is really bad, then change the reference type to `Sudoku.SudokuIterator`

Comment: Thank you. That seems to have worked. I must have the classes in default package. I'll have to look into that. Thanks again.